# Absolute path for the internal storage on iOS device

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using PCLStorage to interact with local files on both Android and iOS platforms.

I am using the following code snippet.

```
IFolder rootFolder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("HandSAppPdf", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Hello.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

in the case of Android, I have the

```
path ="/storage/emulated/0/"
```

But I am not sure what would be the path in the case of iOS. if anyone can help me out, I would much appreciate that.

Comment: use [Environment.SpecialFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#working-with-internal-storage) to get the path to storage for your application

Comment: will the user be able to access the special folder from outside the app?

Comment: You didn’t say that was a requirement

Comment: that's the requirement too. can you guide me further on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your application’s access to the file system (and other resources such as the network and hardware features) is limited for security reasons. This restriction is known as the [Application Sandbox.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Since iOS11, Files App in your phone has been used for users to access the document which an iOS application created. I recommend you to follow this [File system access in Xamarin.iOS and its demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system). You could generate a new text file in  your Application's Documents Folder like this:

```
    public static string WriteFile()
    {
        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "Write.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(filename, "Write this text into a file!");

        return "Text was written to a file." + Environment.NewLine
             + "-----------------" + Environment.NewLine
             + File.ReadAllText(filename);
    }
```

And this file could be accessed through Files App.
Also to allow the user to directly access files in your app, remember to create a new boolean key in the Info.plist file **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace** and set it to true.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have been doing some research and setting the key `Supports Document Browser` in the Info.plist file to `true` created an app folder in the Files app but it's further empty. I was expecting it to contain the app's Data container i.e Documents, Library folders.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19juN5-DPz8An8ZChElkyiysZHiy5YFAb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, Files App could only access the app's Documents directory  instead of the application's root folder.  The file you generate in Documents folder could be seen in Files App after you properly set the key in info.plist.